# Custom photos as a folders miniatures icons

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to have a photos as a miniatures of the folders, in any way?
If folder would contain graphic files like .jpg - could that be shown on the folder icon like it its in windows explorer?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, there is no out of the box way to change the icons of folders with customized image.

kindly, I recommend you give suggestion in the [feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/) to make our products and services better for you and others.